# Session Management

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

I'm using sessions for my login page that will hold the userId in a session. If two different users are logged using the same system and same browser but with separate tabs of the browser, the session value of userid is getting reset to the user who logged in last. Why?

Comment: It's either asp.net or asp-classic, not both. Please fix the tags.

Comment: A good article on secure session management that you will find quite useful: http://www.linuxforu.com/2011/02/securing-apache-part-6-attacks-session-management/

Answer (score 6):

there would be only one `sessionID` saved (in cookie) for a domain by the browser, which would be returned to server on subsequent postbacks to identify the session..

if you open another tab and login as other person, then the latest `sessionID` will override the previous..

So its not possible to have different logins on a same browser..but to use a different browser(not another instance of same browser)

Answer (score 5):

If you are tracking authenticated users with cookies there is no way to achieve this because cookies are shared between browser tabs. It's the same with most sites. Take for example Gmail: you sign-in with one account, then you open a new tab and you are automatically logged in with the same user because the cookies are shared.

In order to achieve what you are asking you basically will have to change the way you are tracking your authenticated users. You should no longer use cookies.

2 possibilities come to mind:

- Use a hidden field on each page that will contain the session id
- Append the session id to the query string of all requests

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible since sessions are shared between tabs. They need to use different browsers or the last user session will delete the previous user session

Comment: Sessions are not shared between tabs. Cookies are shared between tabs (obviously assuming those tabs are pointing to the same domain). So if you are tracking user sessions using cookies, as a consequence of those cookies being shared, sessions will also be shared. But if you change the way you are tracking your authenticated users and do not use cookies, sessions will not be shared between tabs.

Comment: True, when i said sessions i was assuming that cookies are used. Setting the cookieless option to use the url on the web.config works. But is unsafe, so thats why i didnt even think of it.

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer offers a "New Session" feature on its File menu.  This will allow a second user to login to your site whilst another is already logged in.  However this will launch a new window, its not possible to run a separate session in another tab.

Other browsers may offer a similar function.